# usort did not sort multi array in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do I sort an array based on a string? 
The below code didnt work in sorting my array by guardian_last_name. I got the below code from a previous answer to sort by string. This question has been asked many times but the below code should have worked.

I am sorting by the last name and you can see it doesnt sort by last name. The resultant array is below. My questions is straightforward. How do I sort a multi dimensional array in alphabetical order of guardian last name?

```
      usort($data, 'sortByOption');
              function sortByOption($a, $b) {
                  return strcmp($a['guardian_last_name'], $b['guardian_last_name']);
              }

    (int) 0 => [
        'guardian_first_name' => 'amy',
        'guardian_last_name' => 'mael',
        'guardian_id' => (int) 482
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'guardian_first_name' => 'pen',
        'guardian_last_name' => 'kuehn',
        'guardian_id' => (int) 244
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'guardian_first_name' => 'amy',
        'guardian_last_name' => 'mael',
        'guardian_id' => (int) 54
```

Comment: What do you want the results like?

Comment: Will someone guess your question correctly ? Why do you hesitate to explore little more ? Like what does the array look like before sorting, And what kind of result do you expect from that ?

Comment: You can use cakephp `Hash:sort` https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake\Utility\Hash::sort. So in your case `Hash::sort($data, '{n}.guardian_last_name', 'asc');`

Comment: I am sorting by the last name and you can see it doesnt sort by last name. The resultant array is above. My questions is straightforward. How do I sort a multi dimensional array in alphabetical order of guardian last name.

Comment: This did work but i was hoping for a php solution so I can use it elsewhere on a non cakephp project   $data2=  Hash::sort($data, '{n}.guardian_last_name', 'asc');

Comment: can not reproduce